# Stopping an action while action is already running ins SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a space game that I have been expanding from day to day now and I am having an issue that I can't get my head round. Right now I added a PowerUp for my Spaceship which gives it a Shield. The Shield PowerUps spawn with a duration of 37.5 and a range of 15. Which is perfect for me. How ever I would like to figure out (or be shown) how I can make this shield only last a set amount of Seconds.

Right now it lasts until it is hit, which is one way to lose it, but I would also like to have a timer on it.

This is my function that activates the Shield which is called when colliding with the PowerUp:

```
func activateShield() {

    let shield1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-1")
    let shield2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-2")
    let shield3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-3")
    let shield4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-4")
    let shield5 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-5")
    let shield6 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-6")

    let animateShield = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0, withRange: 0),
        SKAction.animate(with: [shield1,shield2,shield3,shield4,shield5,shield6], timePerFrame: 0.10)])
    let animateRepeatShield = SKAction.repeatForever(animateShield)

    shield = SKSpriteNode(texture: shield1)
    shield.name = "ShieldActive"
    shield.setScale(1.5)
    shield.position = player.position
    shield.zPosition = 3
    shield.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: shield.size)
    shield.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    shield.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ShieldActive
    shield.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Enemy
    shield.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Enemy | PhysicsCategories.Life
    shield.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    shield.physicsBody!.density = 0
    self.addChild(shield)
    shield.run(animateRepeatShield)

    let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: player.physicsBody!, bodyB:shield.physicsBody!, anchor:player.position)
    self.physicsWorld.add(joint)
}
```

Here is the other part of my code that has the SKActions in it:

```
    let spawnShield = SKAction.run(spawnAShield)
    let waitToSpawnShield = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 37.5, withRange: 15) //Spawn time between 30 - 45 seconds
    let spawnSequenceShield = SKAction.sequence([waitToSpawnShield, spawnShield])
    let spawnForeverShield = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnSequenceShield)
    self.run(spawnForeverShield, withKey: "spawningShieldPowerUps")
```

Comment: what is spawnAShield? is it supposed to be activateShield()?

Comment: Well it works like this, spawnAShield is the functions that calls the PowerUp icon in the game, once my ship catches that the activateShield function is the actual shield, and that is what I need to set to a specific time, so the that player only has the shield for 5 - 10 seconds!

Comment: what is the SKAction.wait(forDuration: 37.5, withRange: 15) for then?

Comment: it makes sure the icon doesn't come every second, it comes in that duration and range on the screen. Wouldn't want to make it too easy for the player

Comment: check out my edit 2 and see if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similarly to Jean-Baptiste's answer you can also run the wait action and execute the deactivate in a completion closure. The closure fires once the wait duration is finished.

> edited to show the code in a func that could be called with different durations

```
var duration: Double = 5 //you can change this to any value. you could even change the value via code for different shields durations
deactivateShield(afterDuation: duration)

func deactivateShield(afterDuation: Double) {
    shield.run(.wait(forDuration: duration)) {
        self.deactivateShield() 
    }
}
```

> edit 2

```
func activateShield() {

    let shield1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-1")
    let shieldImages = [shield1, SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-2"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-3"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-4"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-5"), SKTexture(imageNamed: "shield-6")] 

    let animateShield = SKAction.animate(with: shieldImages, timePerFrame: 0.10)])
    let animateRepeatShield = SKAction.repeatForever(animateShield)

    shield = SKSpriteNode(texture: shield1)
    shield.name = "ShieldActive"
    shield.setScale(1.5)
    shield.position = player.position
    shield.zPosition = 3
    shield.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: shield.size)
    shield.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    shield.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.ShieldActive
    shield.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Enemy
    shield.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Enemy | PhysicsCategories.Life
    shield.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
    shield.physicsBody!.density = 0
    self.addChild(shield)
    shield.run(animateRepeatShield)

    let joint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.joint(withBodyA: player.physicsBody!, bodyB:shield.physicsBody!, anchor:player.position)
    self.physicsWorld.add(joint)

    //turns off the shield in between 5-10 seconds
    shield.run(.wait(forDuration: 7.5, withRange: 2.5)) {
        self.shield.removeFromParent() 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good, but how would I go about setting the self.deactivateShield to a specific time like 5 or 10 seconds?

Comment: that is the duration and range portion of the wait action...se edit to my answer

Comment: I am having trouble getting this to work, red underlines everywhere :-D

Comment: That's the one, perfect! Thanks so much. I am still learning all this, although I am getting the hang of things as far as logic goes, I think my code is a mess and that's the reason why half the time stuff doesn't work right. Thanks so much

Comment: that's how it works...it'll be completely muddled and then one day it starts to actually make sense and you don't have to think about it, it just happens naturally. My advice after seeing your code is use longer and more descriptive variable names. it's a pain to type out but helps remove confusion, not only today but tomorrow when you come back into the code. for example `spawnShield = SKAction.run(spawnAShield)` could be `spawnShieldAction = SKAction.run(spawnAShieldPowerUp)`

Comment: Good to know thank you. Only one thing to figure out now that this little project is done and I can start the next one :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may add an action that "sleeps" for the duration and then execute an appropriate code to "remove" the shield, like:

```
let action = SKAction.sequence([
    SKAction.wait(forDuration: 37.5, withRange: 15),
    SKAction.run({ self.deactivateShield() })
])
```

Comment: That's good, but how would I go about setting the self.deactivateShield to a specific time like 5 or 10 seconds?

Comment: @NorbertHaubner `SKAction.wait(forDuration; 5)` will wait for exactly 5 seconds. Isn't it what you need?

Comment: I tried that, but it's doing what I want. I want the user to have the Shield for 5 seconds. This SKAction does not seem to do that. Unless I am placing it wrong.

I already got it working so that the power comes at the time I want I to. Right now it's all about giving the Shield a duration, so that the user can't run the whole game long with the same shield.

Comment: @NorbertHaubner sorry but this should solve your problem. It is an action that run on a node will trigger deactivate after given duration. Seems that your problem is somewhere else? Didn't run this action on the node as soon as you made the shield?